# Share data between components using Service - IONIC 2, Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic2, angular2-services

Is there any way to send data `{{error.value}}` to another page using a method?

This is my code

```html
<ion-row *ngFor="let errors of adp_principal_menuRS">
          <ion-col class="info-col" col-4>
            <button ion-button color="primary" small (click)="goToErrors(errors.event)">
              {{errors.event}}
            </button>
          </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

```js
goToErrors(menu: string){
    console.log(menu);
    this.navCtrl.push(AdpDetailPage, {

    });
  }
```

I want to send the `{{errors.event}}` value to another page in the `goToErrors()` method.

Thanks!

EDIT: I just achieve what I want. I edited the code

Comment: `goToErrors()` will navigate to another page?

Comment: Yes, and I want to use the value of errors.event in that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you send the value using a [navParam](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/)?

```
goToErrors(menu: string){
    console.log(menu);
    this.navCtrl.push(AdpDetailPage, {
       errorEvent: menu  // <------------------------- Add this line
    });
  }
```

And in your `AdpDetailPage`:

```
export class AdpDetailPage{
 constructor(public navParams: NavParams){

   errorEvent = this.navParams.get('errorEvent');
   console.log("errorEvent= ", errorEvent);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Data can be shared using `BehaviorSubject` between components via service.
Here is an example:

```
// service.ts
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class ShareService {
    private errorSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    error$ = this.errorSource.asObservable();

    setError(error: any){
        this.errorSource.next(error);
    }
```

Set the `error event` in `parent component` using `setError` method and subscribe the `error` in `error component`.

```
  // error component.ts
  constructor(share: ShareService) {
        share.error$.subscribe(Err => this.error = Err);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. My data is from a service and, I need to create another service to share the data what I need to another page?

Comment: Demand of new service depends on the scope of the service.if the data sharing components and data getting service all are within a same module, there is no need for new service.The `errorSource BehaviorSubject` can be implemented in the same service , which is used to get data.

Answer (score 1):

Use event emittor.

```
//Home component.ts import { Events } from 'ionic-angular'; constructor(public events: Events) {} directioChange(user) {this.events.publish('directiochanged', 'true');} //App.component.ts constructor(public events: Events) { events.subscribe('directiochanged', (direction) => { this.isRtl = direction;console.log(direction);});}
```

Comment: Change as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

I generated a Plunker that hopefully matches with what you are trying to do.

https://plnkr.co/edit/MNqpIqJjp5FN30bJd0RB?p=preview

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorService {
  errorInfo: string;
}
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="goToErrors()">{{errors.event}} </button>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  errors = { event: 'Test Error', otherInfo: 'Test Info' };

  constructor(private errorService: ErrorService, private router: Router) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  goToErrors(): void {
    // Code to navigate to the other component
    this.errorService.errorInfo = this.errors.event;
    this.router.navigate(['/a']);
  }
}
```